# Three-way comparison in ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the most concise way to ensure three variables are all equal in ruby? For example

```
dog = 'animal'
cat = 'animal'
chicken = 'animal'
shoe = 'clothing'

# Something like this...which doesn't work
dog == cat == chicken # true   
dog == cat == shoe # false
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most concise way for three elements is (sorry to disappoint you):

```
dog == cat && cat == chicken
```

Of course you can always get clever if you want to...

```
[dog, cat, chicken] == [dog] * 3
[dog, cat, chicken].uniq.length == 1
```

...but that doesn't really make the code more concise (or readable).

I would do something like this if you want a reusable function that can compare *arbitrarily* many elements for equality:

```
def all_equal?(*elements)
  elements.all? { |x| x == elements.first }
end
```

Comment: a cool way to write `all_equal?`: `each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x == y }`.

Answer (score 3):

```
dog == cat && dog == chicken
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Numbers for comparision :

dog = 'animal'

cat = 'animal'

chicken = 'animal'

shoe = 'clothing'

Create an array :

```
arr = [dog, cat, chicken, shoe]
arr_length = arr.reject { |a| a != dog }.length

if arr_length == 0
puts "All numbers are equal"
end
```