# Simple way to test if multiple variables have same value, ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

Is there a simple way of testing that several variables have the same value in ruby?

Something linke this:

```
if a == b == c == d #does not work
   #Do something because a, b, c and d have the same value
end
```

Of course it is possible to check each variable against a master to see if they are all true, but that is a bit more syntax and is not as clear.

```
if a == b && a == c && a == d #does work
    #we have now tested the same thing, but with more syntax.
end
```

Another reason why you would need something like this is if you actually do work on each variable before you test.

```
if array1.sort == array2.sort == array3.sort == array4.sort #does not work
    #This is very clear and does not introduce unnecessary variables
end
#VS
tempClutter = array1.sort
if tempClutter == array2.sort && tempClutter == array3.sort && tempClutter == array4.sort #works
   #this works, but introduces temporary variables that makes the code more unclear
end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Throw them all into an array and see if there is only one unique item.

```
if [a,b,c,d].uniq.length == 1
  #I solve almost every problem by putting things into arrays
end
```

As sawa points out in the comments .one? fails if they are all false or nil.

Comment: Nice. That would definitely be a better way than with the temp variables!

Comment: Note that you cannot use `one?` if they are to be `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 5):

[tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) suggested a very nice approach in his comment to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846080/three-way-comparison-in-ruby):

```
module Enumerable
  def all_equal?
    each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x == y }
  end
end
```

It's the cleanest way to express this I've seen so far.

Comment: I like this solution as well, but without the module extension it is a bit more verbose than Shawn's answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
[a,b,c,d] == [b,c,d,a]
```

Really just:

```
[a,b,c] == [b,c,d]
```

will do

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,1,1]
(a & a).size == 1 #=> true

a = [1,1,2]
(a & a).size == 1 #=> false
```

Comment: shuffle is not valid, it could end up being in the same order.

Comment: @Pitri You know that `[1,1,2].shuffle` returns `[1,1,2]` sometimes, don't you? ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right partially; so deleted. But `shuffle` does always,but when duplicate items will be present ,it would fail. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[b, c, d].all?(&a.method(:==))
```